# Probability Distribution of Sum of Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Imagine I pick a random point $(x,y)$ on a square on the real plane formed by the lines connecting the points $(2,0)$, $(0,2)$, $(-2,0)$, $(0,-2)$. This point is picked with uniform probability. If I then define a new random variable $W$, defined by $W=2X+2Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are the random variables representing the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point, how do I determine the probability distribution of $W$?

Comment: $X+Y$ is uniformly distributed on $(-2,2)$, so $2(X+Y)$ is uniformly distributed on $(-4,4)$. Try drawing a plot for intuition.